# Auto increment record that can be reset

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, database-schema, auto-increment

I am working on an application for a client that owns an ice skating rink and he wants the ability to log each time the zamboni cuts the ice. In explaining to me how the logging system works currently (pen and paper), every time the blade on the zamboni is changed, the cut number restarts at 1. Currently I have my table indexing all of the zamboni cuts, but I want a secondary field that auto_increments as well (for the zamboni blade), and when the blade changes, the count resets. I have never had to do something like this so I don't know where to begin. Thoughts?

Comment: Do you have any code or something? It's hard to say anything without an example of what you have tried, but here it goes: why not `select` the last value of the second column and then add 1? If you want to reset it, just insert a row with the second column's value as a 1. I don't really think that's OK, that's why I didn't made it as a answer, but it's a start.

Comment: Can you provide the table's ddl and a few sample rows of data?

Comment: At the moment I can post code but I left a comment on the answer below trying my best without an example. I can post an example later tonight so if you guys would just bare with this noobie I would appreciate it :)

Comment: @MattSanford I've seen worse. Can you use (for example) pastebin.org to visualize it for us and show how the changes are done?

Comment: I am only responding via my phone at the moment. Family engagements have me away from my computer till later this evening.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two auto increment fields. And why do you even want two? You can always use arithmetical functions in your query.

To reset the auto_increment, do an ALTER TABLE query

```
ALTER TABLE `table` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Maybe this is of your interest: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35449/how-to-use-2-auto-increment-columns-in-mysql-phpmyadmin

Comment: So what happens when the key with value `1` is still in the database?

Comment: If the column is an unique or primary field, it will throw an error.

Comment: I'm away from my code right now but to try and explain it without code: I have an index, the primary key that puts a count to every ice cut. But for insurance purposes, my client needs a second count, one for how many cuts the blade that is currently on the zamboni has done. The blade gets changed every 75-100 cuts. When the blade is changed, so does the count for the blade since it's new. I'm very new to MySQL so I don't have much context for what I could do. I will post a code example later this evening. Hope I explained it not as awful as it seems

Comment: How do you count the ice cut? Do you just insert a new row or are you updating the old row? Because if you're just updating, there is no need to use AUTO_INCREMENT at all. It doesn't increase anything anyway if you update a row.

Comment: Well as of now I am not doing it at all because I wanted to see the best way to go about it. Creating a new row seems a bit unnecessary. Updating an existing row would seem like a job for a php function to prevent having to manually change the number every time, no?

Comment: You can use arithmetic functions to add/subtract/do more math stuff. Example: `UPDATE table SET ice_cuts=ice_cuts+1 WHERE id='1'`

Comment: okay! so that sounds like exactly what I want. Can i do that like so:
`$query = "INSERT INTO 'cut_log' ('driver', 'date1', 'time', 'cut', 'flood', 'notes') VALUES ('$driver', '$date', '$time', '$cut', '$flood', '$notes') UPDATE 'cut_log' SET 'cut_number' = 'cut_number' + 1 WHERE 'id' = 1";`

Comment: Well, you can't do both things at the same time with using a semicolon after your first query, but if you know the id, sure. Otherwise there is a nice php function. [lastinsertid](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php), available for MySQLi too, but I'll just link for PDO now. :)